# CodeIgniter local database connection issue

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have tried this to make local database connection. But it gives this error:

> You have specified an invalid database connection group (ci_test) in your config/database.php file.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',  // pass this
    'username' => 'root',  // pass this
    'password' => '',  // pass this
    'database' => 'ci_test',  // pass this
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array());
```

Comment: do you have any database with the name of ci_test in your phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Please share error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error relates to the connection group, not the database name. The connection group you have specified there is `default`, as shown on the first line: `$db['default']`.

Look for:

```
$active_group = 'ci_test';
```

Replace it with:

```
$active_group = 'default';
```

There is more information in the [codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;


$db['default'] = array(

'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost', //this will be same
'username' => 'root',  //replace with your username
'password' => '',       //replace with your password
'database' => 'test',   //replace with your database name which you want to use
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE);
```

try this. good luck.

Comment: I have just tried this but it gives the same error.

Comment: check your database is correct or not?if it is there check this also in config/autoload.php. check this $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');                you have to add database library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'ci_test',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I hope this will helps you. Thanks!